# Two elements of $X$ are in the same element of the quotient space $X/N(f)$ iff their functional values are the same.

Tags: functional-analysis

Here $f$ is a non-zero linear functional on a vector space $X$. I can show this true for one direction,

> Let $x_1, x_2 \in x + N(f)$
>
> $\implies x_1 = x + y_1, \quad x_2 = x + y_2$, where $y_1, y_2 \in  N(f).$
>
> Then $f(x_1) = f(x) + f(y_1) = f(x) = f(x) + f(y_2) = f(x_2)$.

I'm not sure how to prove the converse holds true too.

Comment: If $f(x)=f(y)$ then $0=f(x)-f(y)=f(x-y)$ by linearity, so $x-y$ is in the null space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As symplectomorphic already pointed out this is just
\begin{align*}
 f(x) = f(y)
 &\iff f(x) - f(y) = 0
 \iff f(x-y) = 0 \\
 &\iff x-y \in N(f)
 \iff x + N(f) = y + N(f).
\end{align*}

Notice however that this is really just a special case of the more general fact that for every linear map $f \colon V \to W$ we have for all $x,y \in V$ that
$$
 f(v) = f(w) \iff v + \ker f = w + \ker f.
$$
The proof of this can be done by the same calculation as before, but I think it is important to realize that this is precisely the statement that the induced linear map
$$
 \hat{f} \colon V/\ker f \to W, \quad v + \ker f \mapsto f(v)
$$
is a monomorphism, i.e. that $\hat{f} \colon V / \ker f \to \mathrm{im} f$ is an isomorphism. So this is also see this as a direct consequence of the first isomorphism theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well make my comment an answer:

If $f(x)=f(y)$, then $0=f(x)-f(y)=f(x-y)$ by linearity, so $x-y$ is in the null space. Hence $x$ and $y$ are mapped to the same element of the quotient space.

Comment: Thanks for your help, hope you didn't mind your answer not being picked as best.